# Unseen classes - 'Other' class or classifying based on the existing classes

Tags: classification

Let's suppose that I have a classifier which detects whether a script of code is written in Python or C++ or Java.

Therefore, my classifier has 3 outputs which give the probabilities that a certain code script is one of these 3 programming languages above.

However, unfortunately, there is the chance that the test data my contain some code scripts written in other programming languages such as Javascript, Ruby, PHP etc.

If I leave my classifier as it is then it going to classify these code scripts as being in Python or C++ or Java and this will be certainly pretty wrong and misleading.

Does it make sense to add another class called 'Other' which would contain code scripts of various other programming languages (Javascript, Ruby, PHP etc) or even irrelevant text to cope with that?

Is there any better idea?

Comment: I think your approach makes sense. Of course it would be best to have all possible outcomes (classes) in the training set, but this might not be possible. With the „other“ class you may at least avoid that code snippets are classified entirely wrong. Ultimately, it is about testing the approach, but I can imagine that it works well.

Comment: Thanks @Peter , I will listen to the opinions of others too and think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely add more samples and tag it as other with your classifier. However, realistically this might not be an option. For this exact purpose, you could use confidence values with the output of your classifier to predict the "other" class. You could bring in confidence thresholding to support this, i.e if your classifier is not confident > 0.8 (as an example) with its prediction, then you tag it "other" class.

What is the best value to threshold with, you can identify by running a number of experiments with different threshold values and plot a graph for correctness i.e classification error rate graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your idea sounds pretty reasonable (and I have thought about it too) but 1) How? (Do you have any source code for this?), 2) How easy is it to do this? If it is quite time intensive then I do not know if it is worth it for a quick prototype.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit I am going to assume you are using sklearn here. If yes, then you can refer to the following thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129592/how-to-get-a-classifiers-confidence-score-for-a-prediction-in-sklearn

Comment: Thanks, I have actually seen this post. However, `predict_proba` is not really a confidence score which will help in the case of unseen classes because in `predict_proba` the output probabilities always sum up to 1. It would be interesting if we could have some output probabilities that do not necessarily sum up to 1 but they may be all very low and let's say sum up to 0.3 if an irrelevant text is given as an input.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Usually predictions are probabilities, the one with the highest is chosen as the main class. As the case with probabilities, they always add up to 1. For example, in your scenario, if your model does not with 0.7 or 0.8 probability suggest the piece of code belong to a class, you can discard it and label it as other.

Comment: This could serve quite handy if you were to implement prediction intervals for your predicted value : https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-generate-prediction-intervals-with-scikit-learn-and-python-ab3899f992ed

Comment: Regarding your first comment, maybe but still this may happen in many cases at "seen" classes (Python, C++, Java) so I am not sure about that. Also, in a bizarre world, if I also have "a code script" which half is written in Python and half is written in Java then your idea would be again a problem (do not ask me why but I will have data like these).

Comment: Regarding your second comment, thanks and it looks interesting (upvote overall for your effort) but see point (2) of my first comment at your post.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - After some thinking and discussion with peers, what you could also do to generate confidence intervals are as follows:

1. You can do random sampling of your dataset, n times, with repetitions
2. Generate a statistic for your sample, lets say F-score here
3. You now have a distribution of F-scores for all your samples.
4. On this distribution, compute your confidence intervals.

Comment: Ok thanks; I will keep this in mind. Although I do not know how reliable this will be.